# Is there a way to install Mercurial on Ubuntu focal withiout Python2?

Tags: python, mercurial

I took great care not to include python 2.x on my latest Ubuntu focal amd64 systems.  I made the mistake of installing mercurial (sudo apt install mercurial) without paying attention.   It installed the following packages.

```
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  python3-magic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython2-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib mercurial-common python2 python2-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal
Suggested packages:
  kdiff3 | kdiff3-qt | kompare | meld | tkcvs | mgdiff qct python-mysqldb python-openssl python-pygments wish python2-doc python-tk python2.7-doc binfmt-support
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpython2-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib mercurial mercurial-common python2 python2-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal
```

Is there a way to avoid python2?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, starting from Mercurial v5.2:

```sh
python3 -m pip install mercurial
```

See https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Python3